# How should a question like this be answered?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

Consider this question: [Mathematica evaluates expression once, then returns the expression unevaluated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798435/mathematica-evaluates-expression-once-then-returns-the-expression-unevaluated).

The apparently definitive answer was provided in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798435/mathematica-evaluates-expression-once-then-returns-the-expression-unevaluated#comment-9501323) by a [Wolfram Research employee](http://www.linkedin.com/pub/daniel-lichtblau/4/698/133). Yet the question remains [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes). Two different attempts have been made to translate the comment into an answer, but both were deleted by moderators.

How then may this question finally be resolved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Considering how urgently this one question needed to be resolved, I have done so.

Closed as too localized.

The question is about a bug that will be fixed eventually, therefore the issue is localized to a specific version of the product.

If you don't like that resolution, I can reopen and close as "not a real question."  It is a bug, after all, and cannot be answered.  "Its a bug, derp" isn't an answer.

If that doesn't suit you, I could reopen and then we can all pretend that the question doesn't exist.  That's always my favorite solution.

Comment: Seems very reasonable to me; +1

Comment: I think Closed is better than Unanswered.  Why is "it's a bug" not a reasonable answer if it either cites an official source, or directly originates from one?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: "Its a bug" isn't an answer.  "Its a bug; here's the bug report [link], here's the developer commentary on the bug [link], here's the etc etc" would be an answer.  Doubt seriously we'd get one.

Comment: Okay. (87654321)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard just for giggles, here's an example of the pattern, "its a bug, here's the bug report, developer commentary on the bug " http://stackoverflow.com/a/8299981/119477

Comment: @ConradFrix: And notice who gave the answer... Eric Friggen Lippert -- `a principal developer on the Microsoft Visual C# compiler team`.